# A weird differential equation with some unknown trick?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the differential equation I need to solve:
$$y=xy'+k\cdot \frac{y'}{y'-1}$$

(Here $k$ is a given constant).

What I have thought initially is to rewrite $\frac{y'}{y'-1}$ as $\left(1+\frac{1}{y'-1}\right)$. But I don't think it helps that much. Hope someone could give me a hint.

Also, in the question, we are asked to consider $k>0$ and $k<0$ separately. There is definitely a reason why behind this, but I have not figured that out.

Thanks :))

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$y=xy'+k\cdot \frac{y'}{y'-1}$$
Is of the form
$$y=xp+f(p)$$ where $p=y'$
This is Clairaut's differential equation.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not notice that this was a Clairaut's DE. I think I can solve this! Very appreciated.

Comment: @AlroyZhang you're welcome. The wikipedia page is really good fot this Differential Equation...It won't be difficult to solve.